# Java AWS 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Tags: java, angular, spring, amazon-web-services

I am having a problem uploading files to S3 Bucket after I've uploaded and deployed my Spring Boot/Angular application to Elastic Beanstalk. I get, 413 (Request Entity Too Large). I have tried uploading a zipped folder with the .ebextensions directory with the myconf.conf file. Still end up with the same result as well as a blocked by CORS policy. Obviously just running the spring boot app and using postman, everything worked fine and everything worked on localhost:4200 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the max size of the body configuring the Nginx reverse proxy in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:

```
client_max_body_size 2M;
```

You can also configure Nginx via ebextensions (in .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf)